# Extract values from a Ruby hash using values_at by passing an array of keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to extract the values of a hash through the keys passed in as a argument:

```
def menu
  @menu = {"burger" => 5, "chips" => 2, "coke" => 1}
end

def receive_order(*items)
  raise "Sorry not in stock" if items.all? { |key|@menu.has_key?(key) } == false
  :ordered if items.all? { |key|@menu.has_key?(key) }
  # I was hoping to do something like this...
  bill << menu.values_at(items)
  # bill being an empty array
end
```

I've played around with this in IRB and it returns `[nil]`. Would anyone be able to explain why?

If I enter the following:

```
menu.values_at("burger", "chips")
```

I get:

```
=> [5,2]
```

So why won't it work when passed in as an argument?

Comment: `:ordered if items.all? { |key|@menu.has_key?(key) }` doesn't do anything, btw. Also, the extra comparison is kind of redundant. We already know that will be true, since if it isn't true then the previous line would have already raised an exception.

Comment: in your method all you would need is to change `menu.values_at(items)` to `menu.values_at(*items)`. When calling you have designed it to accept an indefinite amount of arguments. The splat (`*`) will cast these into an `Array` but values at also accepts an indefinite amount of arguments so you need to splat the `Array` to split it back out into arguments. e.g. `receive_order('burger','chips')` means `items = ['burger','chips']` so `menu.values_at(items)` is the same as `menu.values_at(['burger','chips'])` where as `menu.values_at(*items)` is the same as `menu.values_at('burger','chips')`

Answer (score 8):

`Hash#values_at` will work if you [splat the array](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html) instead of passing the array itself.

In the posted example, the method `values_at` in `Hash` is considering the passed array as a single key rather than the individual elements of the array as separate keys.

Try:

```
bill << menu.values_at(*items)
```

Example in REPL (`irb`/`pry`):

```
>> hash = {a: 12, b: 7, c: 23}
=> {:a=>12, :b=>7, :c=>23}
>> keys_to_search = [:a, :b]
=> [:a, :b]
>> hash.values_at keys_to_search
=> [nil]
>> hash.values_at *keys_to_search
=> [12, 7]
```

Comment: You're not really passing a "splat". A "splat" is a common-name for the `*` operator, which "splats" the array into its elements. Also, when linking to a non-Stack Overflow site, it's a good idea to extract and summarize the information on that page you find significant. Otherwise, if that link breaks, your answer won't make as much sense or be as useful.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks! Yes, you are indeed right. *splatting the array* is the correct usage. Will take care next time to summarize content.

Answer (score 4):

There are few problems in addition to the omission of the splat in `values_at` and also some opportunities for improvements.

You begin with:

```
def menu
  @menu = {"burger" => 5, "chips" => 2, "coke" => 1}
end
```

There is no point in both returning the hash when `menu` is called and setting the instance variable `@menu` equal to that hash.  I suggest you replace that with either:

```
@menu = {"burger" => 5, "chips" => 2, "coke" => 1}
```

or

```
def menu
  {"burger" => 5, "chips" => 2, "coke" => 1}
end
```

and obtain the hash from your `receive_order` method by referencing `@menu` or `menu`, respectively.

Next, why would you want to raise an exception if an item is not in stock? That seems rather drastic for what must be a common situation. I expect you should handle that in a more graceful way. On the other hand, maybe every element of `item` is supposed to be a key in the hash and the message is misleading. Let's have a look at that line of code, however:

```
raise "Sorry not in stock" if items.all? { |key| @menu.has_key?(key) } == false
```

That's somewhat confusing. Better to write:

```
raise "Sorry not in stock" unless items.all? { |key| @menu.has_key?(key) }
```

but better yet:

```
raise "Sorry not in stock" if (items - @menu.keys).any?
```

Wouldn't `@menu["chips"] = 0` also signify that "chips" are not in stock?  If so, and also assuming that an exception should raised when an element of `item` is not a key in the hash) change the above to:

```
raise "No keys in @menu for elements @{items - @menu.keys} of items" \
  if (items - @menu.keys).any?
if @menu.values_at(*items).any?(&:zero?)
  puts "Sorry not in stock"
  <do something else?>
else
  ...
end
```

As was mentioned in a comment, in:

```
:ordered if items.all? { |key|@menu.has_key?(key) }
```

you need to replace `:ordered` with code that actually does something. But do you need the `if` clause?  If the exception is not raised in the first line, the `if` clause must evaluate `true`, so "no", you don't need the `if` clause.

Next, an exception is raised when (after adding the missing splat) you execute:

```
bill << menu.values_at(*items)
  # NameError: undefined local variable or method `bill' for main:Object
```

because `bill` has not been initialized. I think you want just:

```
bill = menu.values_at(*items)
```

but then you don't do anything with `bill`, other than return its value from the method (since it is the value of the last expression evaluated before the method returns). You therefore can replace that with just:

```
menu.values_at(*items)
```

Putting this together, we may have something like this:

```
@menu = {"burger" => 5, "chips" => 2, "coke" => 1}

def receive_order(*items)
  raise "No keys in @menu for elements @{items - @menu.keys} of items" \
    if (items - @menu.keys).any?
  if @menu.values_at(*items).any?(&:zero?)
    puts "Sorry not in stock"
    <do something else?>
  else
    <perform some action when everything is in stock>
  end
  @menu.values_at(*items)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I sent you off on a tangent slightly though...the value's you see were meant to be the price, but that was going to be my next step of adding a stocklist of some sort, so you've helped me out anyway! There was already a bill initialized as an empty array. The aim was to get the values ordered into that array, apologies if I didn't make that more clear.